# An exception occurred processing [/testpage.jsp] at line [91]

Tags: pentaho, olap, mondrian

I Am trying to install Mondrian using tomcat and mysql
Here is the link to tutorial iam following:
http://hamdihasnaoui.weebly.com/tutorials/instalation-and-confuguration

**edit:
I have attached an image for further info**

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7IDW.png)

**I have tried all the solutions i could find but cannot find an answer.
Here are the error messages:
JPivot had an error ...
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing [/testpage.jsp] at line [91] 88: 89: <%-- render toolbar --%> 90: 91:
92: <%-- if there was an overflow, show error message --%> 93: 94:
Stacktrace:
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing [/testpage.jsp] at line [91]**

88: 
89: <%-- render toolbar --%>
90: 
91:

92: <%-- if there was an overflow, show error message --%>
93: 
94:

Stacktrace:
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:625)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:499)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at

```
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.tonbeller.wcf.controller.RequestFilter$MyHandler.normalRequest(RequestFilter.java:139)
    at 

com.tonbeller.wcf.controller.RequestFilter.doFilter(RequestFilter.java:264)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:200)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:836)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1839)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: com.tonbeller.wcf.utils.SoftException: javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program%20Files\Apache%20Software%20Foundation\Tomcat%209.0\webapps\mondrian\WEB-INF\jpivot\toolbar\htoolbar.xsl (The system cannot find the path specified)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:663)
        at org.apache.jsp.testpage_jsp._jspService(testpage_jsp.java:316)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:476)
        ... 29 more
    Caused by: com.tonbeller.wcf.utils.SoftException: javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program%20Files\Apache%20Software%20Foundation\Tomcat%209.0\webapps\mondrian\WEB-INF\jpivot\toolbar\htoolbar.xsl (The system cannot find the path specified)
        at com.tonbeller.wcf.utils.XmlUtils.getTransformer(XmlUtils.java:95)
        at com.tonbeller.wcf.utils.XmlUtils.getTransformer(XmlUtils.java:109)
        at com.tonbeller.wcf.component.RendererTag.doEndTag(RendererTag.java:134)
        at org.apache.jsp.testpage_jsp._jspx_meth_wcf_005frender_005f0(testpage_jsp.java:1433)
        at org.apache.jsp.testpage_jsp._jspService(testpage_jsp.java:240)
        ... 32 more
    Caused by: javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program%20Files\Apache%20Software%20Foundation\Tomcat%209.0\webapps\mondrian\WEB-INF\jpivot\toolbar\htoolbar.xsl (The system cannot find the path specified)
        at org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTemplates(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:1002)
        at com.tonbeller.wcf.utils.XmlUtils.getTransformer(XmlUtils.java:89)
        ... 36 more
    Caused by: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program%20Files\Apache%20Software%20Foundation\Tomcat%209.0\webapps\mondrian\WEB-INF\jpivot\toolbar\htoolbar.xsl (The system cannot find the path specified)
        at org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTemplates(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:996)
        ... 37 more
    Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program%20Files\Apache%20Software%20Foundation\Tomcat%209.0\webapps\mondrian\WEB-INF\jpivot\toolbar\htoolbar.xsl (The system cannot find the path specified)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTemplates(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:972)
        ... 37 more



    javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: com.tonbeller.wcf.utils.SoftException: javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program%20Files\Apache%20Software%20Foundation\Tomcat%209.0\webapps\mondrian\WEB-INF\jpivot\toolbar\htoolbar.xsl (The system cannot find the path specified)
    javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: com.tonbeller.wcf.utils.SoftException: javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program%20Files\Apache%20Software%20Foundation\Tomcat%209.0\webapps\mondrian\WEB-INF\jpivot\toolbar\htoolbar.xsl (The system cannot find the path specified)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:663)
        at org.apache.jsp.testpage_jsp._jspService(testpage_jsp.java:316)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:476)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at com.tonbeller.wcf.controller.RequestFilter$MyHandler.normalRequest(RequestFilter.java:139)
        at com.tonbeller.wcf.controller.RequestFilter.doFilter(RequestFilter.java:264)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:200)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:836)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1839)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: com.tonbeller.wcf.utils.SoftException: javax.xml.transform.Tran

sformerConfigurationException: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program%20Files\Apache%20Software%20Foundation\Tomcat%209.0\webapps\mondrian\WEB-INF\jpivot\toolbar\htoolbar.xsl (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at com.tonbeller.wcf.utils.XmlUtils.getTransformer(XmlUtils.java:95)
    at com.tonbeller.wcf.utils.XmlUtils.getTransformer(XmlUtils.java:109)
    at com.tonbeller.wcf.component.RendererTag.doEndTag(RendererTag.java:134)
    at org.apache.jsp.testpage_jsp._jspx_meth_wcf_005frender_005f0(testpage_jsp.java:1433)
    at org.apache.jsp.testpage_jsp._jspService(testpage_jsp.java:240)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program%20Files\Apache%20Software%20Foundation\Tomcat%209.0\webapps\mondrian\WEB-INF\jpivot\toolbar\htoolbar.xsl (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTemplates(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:1002)
    at com.tonbeller.wcf.utils.XmlUtils.getTransformer(XmlUtils.java:89)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program%20Files\Apache%20Software%20Foundation\Tomcat%209.0\webapps\mondrian\WEB-INF\jpivot\toolbar\htoolbar.xsl (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTemplates(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:996)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program%20Files\Apache%20Software%20Foundation\Tomcat%209.0\webapps\mondrian\WEB-INF\jpivot\toolbar\htoolbar.xsl (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTemplates(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:972)
    ... 37 more


com.tonbeller.wcf.utils.SoftException: javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program%20Files\Apache%20Software%20Foundation\Tomcat%209.0\webapps\mondrian\WEB-INF\jpivot\toolbar\htoolbar.xsl (The system cannot find the path specified)
com.tonbeller.wcf.utils.SoftException: javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program%20Files\Apache%20Software%20Foundation\Tomcat%209.0\webapps\mondrian\WEB-INF\jpivot\toolbar\htoolbar.xsl (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at com.tonbeller.wcf.utils.XmlUtils.getTransformer(XmlUtils.java:95)
    at com.tonbeller.wcf.utils.XmlUtils.getTransformer(XmlUtils.java:109)
    at com.tonbeller.wcf.component.RendererTag.doEndTag(RendererTag.java:134)
    at org.apache.jsp.testpage_jsp._jspx_meth_wcf_005frender_005f0(testpage_jsp.java:1433)
    at org.apache.jsp.testpage_jsp._jspService(testpage_jsp.java:240)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:476)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.tonbeller.wcf.controller.RequestFilter$MyHandler.normalRequest(RequestFilter.java:139)
    at com.tonbeller.wcf.controller.RequestFilter.doFilter(RequestFilter.java:264)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:200)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:836)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1839)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program%20Files\Apache%20Software%20Foundation\Tomcat%209.0\webapps\mondrian\WEB-INF\jpivot\toolbar\htoolbar.xsl (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTemplates(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:1002)
    at com.tonbeller.wcf.utils.XmlUtils.getTransformer(XmlUtils.java:89)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program%20Files\Apache%20Software%20Foundation\Tomcat%209.0\webapps\mondrian\WEB-INF\jpivot\toolbar\htoolbar.xsl (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTemplates(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:996)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program%20Files\Apache%20Software%20Foundation\Tomcat%209.0\webapps\mondrian\WEB-INF\jpivot\toolbar\htoolbar.xsl (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTemplates(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:972)
    ... 37 more


javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program%20Files\Apache%20Software%20Foundation\Tomcat%209.0\webapps\mondrian\WEB-INF\jpivot\toolbar\htoolbar.xsl (The system cannot find the path specified)
javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program%20Files\Apache%20Software%20Foundation\Tomcat%209.0\webapps\mondrian\WEB-INF\jpivot\toolbar\htoolbar.xsl (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTemplates(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:1002)
    at com.tonbeller.wcf.utils.XmlUtils.getTransformer(XmlUtils.java:89)
    at com.tonbeller.wcf.utils.XmlUtils.getTransformer(XmlUtils.java:109)
    at com.tonbeller.wcf.component.RendererTag.doEndTag(RendererTag.java:134)
    at org.apache.jsp.testpage_jsp._jspx_meth_wcf_005frender_005f0(testpage_jsp.java:1433)
    at org.apache.jsp.testpage_jsp._jspService(testpage_jsp.java:240)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:476)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.tonbeller.wcf.controller.RequestFilter$MyHandler.normalRequest(RequestFilter.java:139)
    at com.tonbeller.wcf.controller.RequestFilter.doFilter(RequestFilter.java:264)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:200)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:836)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1839)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program%20Files\Apache%20Software%20Foundation\Tomcat%209.0\webapps\mondrian\WEB-INF\jpivot\toolbar\htoolbar.xsl (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTemplates(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:996)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program%20Files\Apache%20Software%20Foundation\Tomcat%209.0\webapps\mondrian\WEB-INF\jpivot\toolbar\htoolbar.xsl (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTemplates(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:972)
    ... 37 more
---------
javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program%20Files\Apache%20Software%20Foundation\Tomcat%209.0\webapps\mondrian\WEB-INF\jpivot\toolbar\htoolbar.xsl (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTemplates(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:996)
    at com.tonbeller.wcf.utils.XmlUtils.getTransformer(XmlUtils.java:89)
    at com.tonbeller.wcf.utils.XmlUtils.getTransformer(XmlUtils.java:109)
    at com.tonbeller.wcf.component.RendererTag.doEndTag(RendererTag.java:134)
    at org.apache.jsp.testpage_jsp._jspx_meth_wcf_005frender_005f0(testpage_jsp.java:1433)
    at org.apache.jsp.testpage_jsp._jspService(testpage_jsp.java:240)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:476)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.tonbeller.wcf.controller.RequestFilter$MyHandler.normalRequest(RequestFilter.java:139)
    at com.tonbeller.wcf.controller.RequestFilter.doFilter(RequestFilter.java:264)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:200)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    at
```

Comment: I think you are making things complected. you want to setup mondrian on pentaho correct ? 
Download pentaho schema workbench from pentaho community website. extract the zip launch the application and start working.
only config required is JAVA_HOME

Comment: I am installing pentaho schema workbench(which is now mondrian as official website redirects toward it) using tomcat server and mysql for datasource.I have added an image for info